# Mobipick set default value dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I have been trying to set a date as default dynamically for Mobipick on this way:

1 . I created a variable with the date, then set it into the input text

```
var newFormat = anio + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;
$("#fechaCita").val(newFormat);
```

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" id="fechaCita"/>
```

2 . I have tried to  trigger the event create or add the attribute directly.

```
$("#fechaCita").attr('value',newFormat).trigger('create');
```

However even when the input box displays the correct date, when I click on the datepicker it has the date of today, so I don't know what else to try.